# What property str or int will take less place in Google App Engine (including index)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I want to construct model with properties in form of lists.

```
class Data(db.Model):
    listOfIntergers = db.ListProperty(int)
    listOfStrings = db.ListProperty(str)
```

On both list I want to keep list of values in range <0, 255>.

What **property type will take less space** including index listOfIntergers or listOfStrings in data store?

Consider that str could be characters or encoded hex value i.e. 0 = 0, 255 = ff.

Comment: you might find this useful https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/storage_breakdown

Comment: Quite good it looks than str is better to use than integer since 4 times shorter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be careful! First of all, integers are encoded using a variable-length encoding, so not all int64 values take up 8 bytes -- small values take up 1-2 bytes. However, the representation of list properties repeats the property name for each value in the list.  I rewrote your example using NDB (because the API for getting the encoded protobuf out of it is easier to remember) and found the following:

```
>>> from ndb import *
>>> class Data(Model):
...   listOfIntegers = IntegerProperty(repeated=True)
...   listOfStrings = StringProperty(repeated=True)
... 
>>> len(Data()._to_pb().Encode())
20
>>> len(Data(listOfIntegers=[0]*100)._to_pb().Encode())
2420
>>> len(Data(listOfIntegers=[255]*100)._to_pb().Encode())
2520
>>> len(Data(listOfStrings=['\x00']*100)._to_pb().Encode())
2420
```

But notice how deceptive: 100 integers of value 0 take 24 bytes per value (most of that is the property name 'listOfIntegers'), but 100 integers of value 255 take 25 bytes per value!  That's the variable-length encoding for you.  100 strings of value '\x00' take 24 bytes per value too -- but notice that 'listOfStrings' is one character shorter than 'listOfIntegers' so the 1-byte string takes up 1 byte more than the integer 0, and the same amount of space as the integer 255.

Unless you really need this field to be indexed, the proper solution is probably to declare a BlobProperty (not a list/repeated property) and store a single string consisting of the desired number of bytes.

```
>>> class Data(Model):
...  b = BlobProperty()
... 
>>> d = Data(b=''.join(map(chr, range(100))))
>>> len(d._to_pb().Encode())
133
>>>
```

That's nearly 20x as compact for the same amount of information!  (Admittedly you could get the list property version down a bit by using a shorter property name, but it would still be way longer.)

Comment: I need **index** on this for fast search thousands of records :)

Thanks for very good advice and code example - it is what I need. I was read before some simplified article where size calculation is little obsolete https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/storage_breakdown.

I found some bug what limit me to use listOfString since SDK not accept [chr(x) for x in range(255)] in db.ListProperty(str) - need to use db since legacy code.

http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7806

Comment: You could use db.ListProperty(db.Blob).  And note that range(255) is probably wrong -- it is missing the last character.

Comment: Thanks I will try db.Blob - the best for bytes if it will be indexed - yes range(255) is misspell should be range(256) :)